# xml to php with filter

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml which i want to filter to show only data from a specify publisher.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
  <book isbn="978-1594489501">
    <title>A Thousand Splendid Suns</title>
    <author>Khaled Hosseini</author>
    <publisher>Riverhead Hardcover</publisher>
    <amazon_price>14.27</amazon_price>
  </book>
  <book isbn="978-1594489587">
    <title>The Brief Wondrous Life of Oscar Wao</title>
    <author>Junot Diaz</author>
    <publisher>AB</publisher>
    <amazon_price>14.97</amazon_price>
  </book>
  <book isbn="978-0545010221">
    <title>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</title>
    <author>J. K. Rowling</author>
    <publisher>AB</publisher>
    <amazon_price>19.24</amazon_price>
  </book>
</books>
```

**i want to put in an html table only data from example publisher AB.**

```
    <?php
// load SimpleXML
$books = new SimpleXMLElement("books.xml);
 $myVar="AB";  
 $books = $s->xpath("//book");
echo <<<EOF
<table style='width: 99%;'>
       <thead>
<tr>

                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>


       </tr>
</thead>

EOF;
foreach($books as $book) // loop through our books
{
           //if the type of $product books user input (ie $myVar)
       if ($book->type == $myVar) 
       {



        echo <<<EOF
        <tbody>
        <tr>

                <td>{$book->title} </td>
                <td>{$book->author}</td>


      </tr>


EOF;
 }}
 echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I am getting **Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object**, any help please.

Comment: Variable $s is undefined in the string `$books = $s->xpath("//book");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load data from a file via [the constructor of SimpleXMLElement](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) you have to set the third parameter to `true`. Otherwise the string you pass as first parameter is interpreted as the "raw" xml data, i.e. either

```
$x = new SimpleXMLELement('<books><book>....</books>');
```

or

```
$x = new SimpleXMLELement('books.xml', 0, true);
```

or

```
$x = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
```

---

and there are some other mistakes in the code. E.g. you want to test for a specific value in the `<publisher>` element but you are testing `if ($book->type == $myVar)`.
It's probably better in this case to put the condition into the xpath expression

```
<?php
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement("books.xml", 0, true);
$myVar="AB"; 
$books = $doc->xpath("//book[publisher='$myVar']");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `$s->xpath("//book")` but it doesn't appear that `$s` exists. I think you meant this line above it:

```
$s = new SimpleXMLElement("books.xml");
```

instead of

```
$books = new SimpleXMLElement("books.xml");
```

and don't forget the closing quote `"` ("books.xml")